# Using "Android System WebView" instead of AOSP

Tags: android, webview, package

i have defined a WebView in a certain layout, and fetching it normally via:

```java
mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

The package of this webview is `com.android.webview`

```
WebViewCompat.getCurrentWebViewPackage(context).packageName
```

And the version is also much older comparing to chrome latest version.

i have installed the [Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en) but it has no use as the SDK uses the default one above.

Is there a way to programmatically use the `com.google.android.webview` over the out-of-the-box one ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem as well.

Comment: nope. you can use Mozilla's GeckoView instead